# why the Graph API - Searching( https://graph.facebook.com/search) only send me 25 results

Tags: api, search, facebook-graph-api, graph

Hi I working with the Graph API  - Searching  (https://graph.facebook.com/search) and every time send me only 25 results and want to know how I can get more of 25 and maybe filter by date.
I hope you can help me

Answer (score 2):

Look at the Paging in the [Graph API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/). Are you sending the "limit" parameter in the request? It looks like it is defaulting to 25 if you don't pass it and you get a paging object in the response which contains request URLs for the next/previous pages and you can use those to easily query the pages and show them.

Sample "paging" object in the search response:

```
"paging": {
  "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=orange&access_token=<your_access_token>&limit=25&since=1333151997&__previous=1",
  "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=orange&access_token=<your_access_token>&limit=25&until=1333151781"
}
```